# Can not find fonts when export pdf using matplotlib Agg backend with usetex=True

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

While running the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import pylab

mpl.use('agg')
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex']=True

pylab.plot(range(5))
pylab.savefig("test.pdf")
```

produce an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bug_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    pylab.savefig("test.pdf")
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1952, in print_pdf
    return pdf.print_pdf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2358, in print_pdf
    file.close()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 507, in close
    self.writeFonts()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 604, in writeFonts
    realpath, stat_key = get_realpath_and_stat(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 982, in __call__
    stat = os.stat(realpath)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<current directury>/cmr17'
```

The font cmr17 do exists in the standard latex distribution. (mf, afm and tfm) files. exporting to postscript or EPS works perfectly. But I want a PDF output to import as image to a XeTeX document. Removing usetex=True part runs OK. But I want my fonts to correspond with my LaTeX document.

What might be wrong?

(Debian unstable, matplotlib 1.3.1, python 2.7, texlive 2013.20140408-1)

Thanks,
Ronen

edit: with '--verbose-debug'

```
$HOME=/home/ronen
matplotlib data path /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data
loaded rc file /home/ronen/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
matplotlib version 1.3.1
verbose.level debug
interactive is True
platform is linux2
loaded modules: <dictionary-keyiterator object at 0x7fa39e47d890>
CACHEDIR=/home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib
Using fontManager instance from /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.cache
backend agg version v2.2
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/928f387fc89d34c34e634e0a7e62c685.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
find_tex_file(pcrr7t.tfm): ['kpsewhich', u'pcrr7t.tfm']
find_tex_file result: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/courier/pcrr7t.tfm
opening tfm file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/courier/pcrr7t.tfm
lh=18, bc=0, ec=170, nw=3, nh=16, nd=16
find_tex_file(pcrr7t.vf): ['kpsewhich', u'pcrr7t.vf']
find_tex_file result: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/adobe/courier/pcrr7t.vf
Dvi: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/adobe/courier/pcrr7t.vf
find_tex_file(pcrr8r.tfm): ['kpsewhich', u'pcrr8r.tfm']
find_tex_file result: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/courier/pcrr8r.tfm
opening tfm file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/courier/pcrr8r.tfm
lh=18, bc=1, ec=255, nw=2, nh=16, nd=16
find_tex_file(pcrr8r.vf): ['kpsewhich', u'pcrr8r.vf']
find_tex_file result: 
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Gamma'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Delta'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Theta'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Lambda'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Xi'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Pi'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Sigma'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Upsilon'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Phi'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Psi'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `Omega'
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: Warning: missing glyph `dotlessj'
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/9fbf3f25dbfd4f5bfc60b39bc1491553.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
find_tex_file(cmr17.tfm): ['kpsewhich', u'cmr17.tfm']
find_tex_file result: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr17.tfm
opening tfm file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr17.tfm
lh=18, bc=0, ec=127, nw=36, nh=16, nd=9
find_tex_file(cmr17.vf): ['kpsewhich', u'cmr17.vf']
find_tex_file result: 
find_tex_file(cmmi12.tfm): ['kpsewhich', u'cmmi12.tfm']
find_tex_file result: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi12.tfm
opening tfm file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi12.tfm
lh=18, bc=0, ec=127, nw=97, nh=15, nd=9
find_tex_file(cmmi12.vf): ['kpsewhich', u'cmmi12.vf']
find_tex_file result: 
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/928f387fc89d34c34e634e0a7e62c685.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/e2d6db7fad01b37ac8a02a8a85387ce8.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/928f387fc89d34c34e634e0a7e62c685.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/fdbe72858be7d78500d8beb017e1c50e.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/928f387fc89d34c34e634e0a7e62c685.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/a8016fb0d928ed1959a912a59552b382.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/928f387fc89d34c34e634e0a7e62c685.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/cb6ad0a1dc1f50bb5ca10571c6efdf30.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/928f387fc89d34c34e634e0a7e62c685.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/7a581e7d191e4f12ac371e0c3fcd8c81.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/928f387fc89d34c34e634e0a7e62c685.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/36bfb83db6bed94b171b0012c6b762ee.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/928f387fc89d34c34e634e0a7e62c685.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/dd2f7eba0d7ff3aedbaa1020460486cd.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/928f387fc89d34c34e634e0a7e62c685.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/efecb62be4d3ddc63f3078bf80db0c27.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Dvi: /home/ronen/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/9fbf3f25dbfd4f5bfc60b39bc1491553.dvi
Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
Assigning font /F1 = cmr17
find_tex_file(pdftex.map): ['kpsewhich', 'pdftex.map']
find_tex_file result: /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
Embedding font cmr17
Writing TrueType font
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is a known bug (#2771)

Comment: It seems different. Running the code from [the original mailing list discussion](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/font-setting-in-matplotlib-1-3-1-td42662.html)  shows no error. +here it's latex specific. 

Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is another issue (that I could not find from my phone) that has to do with font look up in the pgf backend. This may be the related (in that case it was tex but finding fonts)

Comment: 'PGF' backend works well for me. Couldn't find any bug that seems relevant. I want to work with agg in order to have both proper PDF output and PNG inline preview in IPython. 

Anyway, the error exists in in the current  git 'master' brunch.

Comment: added '--verbose-debug' output.

Comment: I filed a bug report
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3019

Comment: I am getting a similar error (only with cmr12 not being found) when running the basic PdfPages example from http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html and posted it as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43609423/2725810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a specific backend in Matplotlib, you need to specify this *before* importing pylab.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('agg')
import pylab

mpl.rcParams['text.usetex']=True

pylab.plot(range(5))
pylab.savefig("test.pdf")
```